# CakePHP find method with JOIN

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, join

Hi,

I need to do the following query using the CakePHP `find` method:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN users ON messages.from = users.id
WHERE messages.to = 4
ORDER BY messages.datetime DESC
```

Basically I have:

- `messages` table with a `Message` model
- `users` table with `User` model

and want to retrieve information from both tables in one query. The `users.id` field is the same as the `messages.from` field, so that's what the join is on.

I am doing it in my `MessagesController` so it would need to be something like:

```
$this->Message->find();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 118, accepted):

There are two main ways that you can do this.  One of them is the standard CakePHP way, and the other is using a custom join.

It's worth pointing out that this advice is for CakePHP 2.x, not 3.x.

## The CakePHP Way

You would create a relationship with your User model and Messages Model, and use the containable behavior:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array('Message');
}

class Message extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

You need to change the `messages.from` column to be `messages.user_id` so that cake can automagically associate the records for you.

Then you can do this from the messages controller:

```
$this->Message->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('User')
    'conditions' => array(
        'Message.to' => 4
    ),
    'order' => 'Message.datetime DESC'
));
```

## The (other) CakePHP way

I recommend using the first method, because it will save you a lot of time and work.  The first method also does the groundwork of setting up a relationship which can be used for any number of other find calls and conditions besides the one you need now.  However, cakePHP does support a syntax for defining your own joins.  It would be done like this, from the `MessagesController`:

```
$this->Message->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'UserJoin',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserJoin.id = Message.from'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Message.to' => 4
    ),
    'fields' => array('UserJoin.*', 'Message.*'),
    'order' => 'Message.datetime DESC'
));
```

Note, I've left the field name `messages.from` the same as your current table in this example.

## Using two relationships to the same model

Here is how you can do the first example using two relationships to the same model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MessagesSent' => array(
            'className'  => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'from'
         )
    );
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'MessagesReceived' => array(
            'className'  => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'to'
         )
    );
}

class Message extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'UserFrom' => array(
            'className'  => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'from'
        )
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'UserTo' => array(
            'className'  => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'to'
        )
    );
}
```

Now you can do your find call like this:

```
$this->Message->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('UserFrom')
    'conditions' => array(
        'Message.to' => 4
    ),
    'order' => 'Message.datetime DESC'
));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I cant change the name of the messages.from column because ive also got a messages.to column that has the recipient user id in it so i cant have two user_id fields. I can do it easy enough with my mysql query is there not a simple way to do it in cake without having to change my tables?

Comment: I did it 'The (other) cakephp way' i think thats much better. Thanks  for all your help your a life saver!

Comment: @geoffs3310 Gave you an even better way in the third example.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm looking to do something like this now but I heard that `contain` will cause an extra query to be ran internally for each row of the main table... rather than just doing a single query with a join. Thoughts on this?

Comment: @smerny I'm not sure, but you could look at your sql logs to verify.

Comment: @Stephen, I actually did look and noticed that in addition to the normal query there is an extra query for each result. I've posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21897352/684368) if you'd like to look.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the advice "The (other) CakePHP way" works in CakePHP 1.3.

Comment: There is a slight difference with your answer and the one that given in the following cakePHP doc : 
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins
I tried your way, it is working fine but I'm unable to use the cakePHP docs way.

Comment: @rahim.nagori as I mentioned in the answer: "It's worth pointing out that this advice is for CakePHP 2.x, not 3.x."

Answer (score 4):

**Otro example, custom Data Pagination for JOIN**

CODE in Controller CakePHP 2.6 is OK:

```
$this->SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds->recursive = -1;
    // Filtro
    $where = array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'usuarios',
                'alias' => 'Usuarios',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Usuarios.usuario_id = SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.usuarios_id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'senasa_pedidos',
                'alias' => 'SenasaPedidos',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'SenasaPedidos.id = SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.senasa_pedidos_id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'clientes',
                'alias' => 'Clientes',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Clientes.id_cliente = SenasaPedidos.clientes_id'
                )
            ),
        ),
        'fields'=>array(
            'SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.*',
            'Usuarios.usuario_id',
            'Usuarios.apellido_nombre',
            'Usuarios.senasa_establecimientos_id',
            'Clientes.id_cliente',
            'Clientes.consolida_doc_sanitaria',
            'Clientes.requiere_senasa',
            'Clientes.razon_social',
            'SenasaPedidos.id',
            'SenasaPedidos.domicilio_entrega',
            'SenasaPedidos.sds',
            'SenasaPedidos.pt_ptr'
        ),
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Clientes.requiere_senasa'=>1
        ),
        'order' => 'SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.created DESC',
        'limit'=>100
    );
    $this->paginate = $where;
    // Get datos
    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate();
    exit(debug($data));
```

**OR Example 2, NOT active conditions:**

```
$this->SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds->recursive = -1;
    // Filtro
    $where = array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'usuarios',
                'alias' => 'Usuarios',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Usuarios.usuario_id = SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.usuarios_id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'senasa_pedidos',
                'alias' => 'SenasaPedidos',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'SenasaPedidos.id = SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.senasa_pedidos_id'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'clientes',
                'alias' => 'Clientes',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Clientes.id_cliente = SenasaPedidos.clientes_id',
                    'Clientes.requiere_senasa = 1'
                )
            ),
        ),
        'fields'=>array(
            'SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.*',
            'Usuarios.usuario_id',
            'Usuarios.apellido_nombre',
            'Usuarios.senasa_establecimientos_id',
            'Clientes.id_cliente',
            'Clientes.consolida_doc_sanitaria',
            'Clientes.requiere_senasa',
            'Clientes.razon_social',
            'SenasaPedidos.id',
            'SenasaPedidos.domicilio_entrega',
            'SenasaPedidos.sds',
            'SenasaPedidos.pt_ptr'
        ),
        //'conditions'=>array(
        //    'Clientes.requiere_senasa'=>1
        //),
        'order' => 'SenasaPedidosFacturadosSds.created DESC',
        'limit'=>100
    );
    $this->paginate = $where;
    // Get datos
    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate();
    exit(debug($data));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        $services = $this->Service->find('all', array(
            'limit' =>4,
            'fields' => array('Service.*','ServiceImage.*'),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'services_images',
                        'alias' => 'ServiceImage',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'conditions' => array(
                        'ServiceImage.service_id' =>'Service.id'
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
```

It goges to array is null.