# How to count the result using find() in CakePHP 2.2.4?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using **Cakephp 2.2.4** and I need to retrive a list of Lead that belongs to the user (**id = 106**).

The result of the query is:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Lead' => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'user_id' => '106',
            'date' => '2012-12-31 22:15:23',
            'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
            'service_id' => '1',
            'location' => 'Rome',
            'message' => 'Message Message',
            'telephone' => null,
            'active' => null
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '106',
            'email' => 'daje@daje.it',
            'pwd' => '0433c024cb08be13000d59a347e640482843f46f177e95749dc6599c259617fd3491dcb940b47693cbbc7f65a2cc5ef62deca2e600c1be133ad54170f7d1fbd1',
            'role_id' => '3',
            'active' => '1'
        ),
        'Service' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Primo servizio'
        ),
        'Estimate' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'lead_id' => '6',
                'user_id' => '106'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

It looks good but I need to count the Estimates (Estimate array), I would like to retrive the number of the estimates, and not the array with all the fields (of estimates table).

How can i do it?

I need :

**Lead** array as it shown

**User** array as it shown

**Service** array as it shown

**Estimate** (only the total number of the estimates... in this case `1`)

The find is very simple:

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 106));

debug($this->Lead->find('all', $options));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, not 100% sure it'll work but worth a go if not I'd advise trawling the cakephp docs for retrieving your data:

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array('Lead.*', 'User.*', 'Service.*', 'count(Estimate.id)'),
    'conditions' => array('User.id' => 106)
);
```

Comment: I get the follow error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Estimate.id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Lead`.*, `User`.*, `Service`.*, count(`Estimate`.`id`), `Lead`.`id` FROM `tuofisco`.`leads` AS `Lead` LEFT JOIN `tuofisco`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Lead`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `tuofisco`.`services` AS `Service` ON (`Lead`.`service_id` = `Service`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`id` = 106

Comment: Hmm, actually you may need to set up a join in the find query manually for the Estimate model. Might be helpful -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079908/cakephp-find-method-with-join

Answer (score 0):

Without diving too far into the internals of the Cake ORM, assuming you don't need to do this immediately at query time, couldn't you just get the `count` of the estimate array programmatically after the fetch?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

```
$leads = $this->Lead->find('all',$options);
foreach($leads as $lead){
  //get the number of estimates for every lead result
  $lead_num = count($lead['Estimate']);
}
```

Alternatively, you could manually write a join query for this one fetch and execute it using the Cake Model class's `query` method.  Without knowing the specifics of your table schema and model relations its hard to give specifics about how to structure the query, but this shouldn't be too difficult by just look at your table spec and extracting a sql `COUNT` statement for every `Estimate` with given id.

Comment: Yes, but, I would like to retrive it directly without count the estimates of each leads. How can I do it ?

Comment: Gonna need to perform a join on the table in SQL query syntax proper, you may want to look into manually writing the query just for this fetch and executing it directly using the `query` method on Cake's Model http://api21.cakephp.org/class/model