# Cakephp return true on findAll if record exists in another model

Tags: php, api, rest, cakephp

I'm currently building a REST api for events with CakePHP. Right now I have an events table and an event_attendees table with columns event_id and user_id. Currently when I send back a list of all the events in response to a user request, each event has fields for its details and, through model linking with the users model, a list of all the users attending it. However, I want each event to also have the field "attending" which indicates whether the CURRENT user is attending the event (this can obviously be figured out by looking at the event_attendees table). So whenever I call findAll() on the Event model, I want each event to have the "attending" field as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079908/cakephp-find-method-with-join).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay away from globals, your best bet is to retrieve a list of events and a list of events for the current user. Two loops and you'll have your list of events with those the user is attending highlighted.

Example:

```
# In the user model
class User extends AppModel {
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Event' => array('class' => 'Event'));
}

# In the controller
$allEvents = $this->Events->find('all');
$userAndEvents = $this->User->findForId($userId);
```

This assumes that you have a many-to-many relationship between your user and your event. In other words, one user can attend many events and an event can be attended by many users.