# Using multiple Models Find() CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have these tables:

table: **CREATORS**

[image: **CREATORS**]

obs.:I've also tried that way:

[image]

table: **POSTS**

[image]

**CreatorModel.php**

```
class CreatorModel extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasOne = array('Post');
}
```

**PostModel.php**

```
class PostModel extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasOne = array('Creator');
}
```

**IndexController.php**

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Post->find());
```

**index.ctp**

```
var_dump($posts);
```

Following the CakeBook session about **Associations**
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

I should receive that response in view:

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [creator_id] => 1
            [tags] => 
            [title] => Teste
            [post] => Maromba
            [created] => 2013-04-29 19:14:32
            [modified] => 2013-04-29 19:14:32

        )
    [Creator] => Array
        (
            [creator_id] => 1
            [creator] => Alexandre Moraes
        )
)
```

But i receive this:

```
Array
(
    [Post] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [creator_id] => 1
            [tags] => 
            [title] => Teste
            [post] => Maromba
            [created] => 2013-04-29 19:14:32
            [modified] => 2013-04-29 19:14:32

        )
)
```

**So, any ideas what i'm doing wrong?**

Comment: You need to read cakephp docs and follow the conventions (it's easier that way) http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: In the db, change `creator_id` for `id` in the table `creators`

Comment: @nuns, still the same response... without the "Creator" key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the db

```
CREATORS TABLE
---
id | creator
```

**Creator.php**

```
class Creator extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasOne = array('Post');
}
```

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo= array('Creator');
}
```

Please note the naming of the models and the association type in Post.php

**IndexController.php**

```
$this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all', array('contain'=>array('Creator')));
```

Doing those changes, the array returned should be the one you're expecting.

Comment: Also change the name of the model files (change it in my answer)

Comment: @Alexandre you might want to read this chapter in the cakephp manual: [CakePHP Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html). This chapter describes how you should name your classes, database-tables and fields so that CakePHP will 'automatically' understand them.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a setup the correct relationships for your models. You're essentially looking to do a join between the two tables. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080026/2297744 I believe it's pretty similar to what you're trying to do.

The quick and dirty version would look something like this:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'creators',
            'alias' => 'CreatorJoin',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'CreatorJoin.id = Post.creator'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But I'd recommend reading the full answer I linked to and using the first (more correct) example.

Comment: I've edited my question showing what i have following the CakeBook. Even with the link you sent i can't get this working. Any idea?