# Join single item from related table based on min of field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have an `Item` model which has the following associations:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id'
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'ItemPic' => array(
        'className' => 'ItemPic',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

I am wanting custom data for different views of `Item`. It seems like CakePHP automatically includes `Project` data (maybe because it is `hasOne`?) and does not include the `ItemPic` data. In the `index` I really don't even want the `Project` data... however, I do want the `ItemPic` data. For each `Item` record pulled, I want a single `ItemPic` record joined to it. This `ItemPic` should be basically `ItemPic.item_id = Item.id` and `ORDER BY ItemPic.rank LIMIT 1`.

The purpose of this is basically so that in the index I can show a list of Items and a picture associated with each item. I would like all of the images along with the `Project` data in the `view` for a single `Item`, but not in the list/index.

I was told I could use `containable` like this:

```
// In the model
public $actsAs = array('Containable');

// In the controller
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'contain' => array(
        'ItemPic' => array(
            'fields' => array('file_name'),
            'order' => 'rank',
            'limit' => 1
        )
    )
);
```

The above actually works how I want... however, I was also told that doing this would cause an extra query to be ran for every single `Item`... which I feel I should avoid.

I tried doing this, but I get duplicate data and it doesn't attach any `ItemPic` data:

```
    $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'joins' =>  array(
                    array(
                            'table' => 'item_pics',
                            'alias' => 'ItemPic',
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                    'ItemPic.item_id = Item.id'
                            ),
                            'order' => 'rank ASC',
                            'limit' => 1
                    )

            )
    );
    $paginated = $this->Paginator->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'joins' =>  array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'item_pics',
                        'alias' => 'ItemPic',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'ItemPic.item_id = Item.id'
                        ),
                        'order' => 'rank ASC',
                        'limit' => 1
                )

        ),
    'fields' => array('Item.*','Project.*','ItemPic.*') 
    );
```

In the fileds section you may or may not assign "Item" , "Project" according to your requirment.

Thanks

Comment: That does seem to work for adding the `ItemPic` stuff, and I can remove the `Project` stuff which is good. However, I am getting duplicate data now. I am getting item 1 with every picture associated with it in different rows instead of just item 1 with its lowest rank limit 1 picture.

Comment: Here is the query it is using with the above: http://pastebin.com/1VWXXGTy (I also notice it is still joining `Project`. And here is the (trimmed down) resulting array: http://pastebin.com/nQkMUiCG

Comment: I assume the `order` and `limit` fields in the `joins` array don't work (or atleast not the way I expected).

Comment: Can you please tell me which version of cake you are using?

Comment: I tagged it, I'm using 2.4

Comment: Can you please try using 'order' => 'ItemPic.rank ASC' instead of 'order' => 'rank ASC'

Comment: That didn't change the results.

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure?