# Join Query CakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I want make a query like that

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`nome`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`slug`,
`Photo`.`id`, `Photo`.`title`, `Photo`.`user_id`,
`Scheda`.`id`, `Scheda`.`user_id`, `Scheda`.`size`, `Scheda`.`weight`,
`Size`.`id`, `Size`.`value`, `Weight`.`id`, `Weight`.`value`
FROM `database`.`users` AS `User`
LEFT JOIN `database`.`photos` AS `Photo`
    ON (`Photo`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `database`.`schedas` AS `Scheda`
    ON (`Scheda`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `database`.`sizes` AS `Size`
    ON (`Size`.`id` = `Scheda`.`size`)
LEFT JOIN `database`.`weights` AS `Weight`
    ON (`Weight`.`id` = `Scheda`.`weight`)
WHERE `slug` = 'alessandro' LIMIT 1
```

How can I do into the controller?

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: This should help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079908/cakephp-find-method-with-join

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like you're just looking for some basic [model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) (User hasMany Photo, User hasMany Scheda, Scheda hasOne Size, Scheda hasOne Weight).

Comment: I can't reply but only comment yet. :-(

Comment: I received an error:
Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Controller/UsersController.php

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I created Model for Size and Weight and then I inserted into the UserController the code:

```
$this->loadModel('Size');      
$size=$this->Size->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array('Scheda.user_id = '.$data['User']['id']),
    'fields'=>array('Size.value')
));
$this->set('size',$size);
```

The only question is...Why into view I must call the value with 0?

```
echo $size['0']['Size']['value']

echo $size['Size']['value'] //didn't work.
```

Alessandro

Comment: two tips 1) don't use string conditions - they offer you no protection from sql injection (compare the code in the answer to `'conditions' => array('Scheda.user_id' => $data['User']['id'])` and consider what happens if that value is "1 OR 1=1") 2) don't ask questions in answers (it's because you're finding _all_ - i.e. more than one result is an expected result). +1 for answering your own question. Actually - I retract that since it looks like you've answered a different question to the one you've asked.