# How to get the data from three tables with join in cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

How to get the data with common package id from three tables with join in cakephp?

package id is common between three tables.

I want to get data from three tables with particular package id.

Is there any query to fetch the data for particular package id from three tables at signle time?

Comment: Specify your table names with their Schema / table fields

Comment: OP , care to check answer ??

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways that you can do this. One of them is the standard **CakePHP way**, and the other is **using a custom join**.

[CakePHP Join Multiple Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080026/2460470)

Answer (score 0):

Joins can be done as follows , substitute your tables instead of mine

Suppose here my table , controller is `CourseLessonsReference` Controller , so I can join other 2 or many tables as follows:

```
$conditionForId = array('CourseLessonsReference.course_id'=>$package_id,
    );  


    //Pagination logic
    $this->paginate = $allConditionsFields = array('conditions' => $conditionSearchLessonsByCourse,                                                                                                 
                            "joins" => array(
                                            array(//UserCourse = Course Join
                                                "table" => "courses",
                                                "alias" => "Course1",
                                                "type" => "INNER",
                                                "conditions" => array(
                                                    "Course1.id = CourseLessonsReference.course_id"
                                                )
                                            ),//For Category = Course Join
                                            array(
                                                "table" => "course_categories",
                                                "alias" => "CourseCategory",
                                                "type" => "INNER",
                                                "conditions" => array(
                                                    "CourseCategory.id = Course1.course_category_id"
                                                )
                                            )
                                        ),
                            'recursive' =>  2                               
                            );


 $resultOfJoin = $this->CourseLessonsReference->find('all', $allConditionsFields);
```

$resultOfJoin will give you result for Joins of 3 tables.

It means join Current table `CourseLessonsReference` with specified tables in Join tag in $allConditionsFields array .

As you didnt provide schema of your tables , Here in my case , Current Controller/model/table is CourseLessonsReference which will have references. References are associated with Course so course_id is foreign key in course_lessons_reference table . So this is 1 join. Now Course is connected to Category so , course will have `course_category_id` as foreign key.