# how to get rows from many to many tables cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

could you help my with retrieve data from databse? I have got 3 tables: `raids`,`teams` and `teams_raids`.

I would like to get all rows from Teams which that are associated with the table raids. Like this http://postimg.org/image/b11nhr53x/ . In my countroler wrote:

```
$usersraids = TableRegistry::get('TeamsRaids'); 
$teamId = $usersraids->find('list', 
    [ 'contain' => ['Teams'],
    ['conditions' => ['raid_id ' => $id, ]
]]);`
```

but i got ALL rows from table TEAM.

Thank for help. Greetings!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP find method with JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079908/cakephp-find-method-with-join)

Comment: its not the same. I have got ManytoMany with pivot table.