# Force Model::find() to reuse a prepared statement in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, prepared-statement

In raw PHP I'd do it like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag=:tag");

foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $sth->bindValue(':tag', $tag);
    $sth->execute(); // followed by fetch, etc.
}
```

In CakePHP I'd have to use the native [`find()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Model.html#_find) function:

```
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $this->Tag->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'tag' => $tag,
        ),
    ));
}
```

I'm pretty sure this will result in CakePHP firing a set of separate database queries which won't utilise [the benefits of having the prepared statement in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467150).

Is there any way I could force CakePHP to do that without modifying the core?

**UPDATE** [There is a way to call `$this->getDataSource()` directly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements) but I'm looking for a way to keep using the `find()` method, if possible, because it [handles contains automatically](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable) and the code for those [complex queries using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080026/722036) and all just looks more elegant that way.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I'd rather execute one single query, if possible, to fetch all required tags, using `$this->Tag->find('all', array(/* ... */))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom/extended datasource, and/or a custom connection class, either could implement an appropriate caching mechanism.

On datasource level, you'd have to re-implement `DboSource::_execute()`. On connection level you'd have to override `PDO::prepare()`.

Just look at what `DboSource::_execute()` currently does:

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../blob/2.7.9/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L448](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.9/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L448)**

It will create a new statement each time it is being invoked, and the only way to hook in without re-implementing the whole method, would be using a custom connection (`$this->_connection`).

However, in order to be able to use a custom connection class, you'd have to re-implement the `connect()` method (implemented by the individual DBO driver classes), which isn't a nice thing to do either.

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../blob/2.7.9/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php#L152](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.9/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php#L152)**

See also **[Cookbook > Models > DataSources](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hoped there would be an easier solution. But I'm sure this will be helpful to whoever chooses to try this, so I'm accepting the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Cake is doing what you want already in the [DboSource](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/source-class-DboSource.html) class for you.

[Just read the code of it](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/source-class-DboSource.html).