# CakePHP Containable: how to set deep conditions?

Tags: php, cakephp

**Model Associations**:

- InfoFaturamento belongs to Contrato
- Contrato has many ContratoCliente
- ContratoCliente has many VwCliente

I want to fetch all `VwClientes` where `InfoFaturamento` equals an id passed by parameter. Is possible to do this without using joins option?

This is the code I tried. It's returning all the `ContratoCliente`:

```
$test = $this->InfoFaturamento->Contrato->ContratoCliente->find('all', [
    'contain' => [
        'Contrato' => [
            'InfoFaturamento' => [
                'conditions' => [
                    'InfoFaturamento.id' => $idInfoFaturamento
                ]
            ]
        ] 
    ],
]);
debug($test); die();
```

All the associations are set in the models.

I know I can do this with recursive option, but I don't like to use this because it returns lots of unnecessary data and it's slow. I could use joins too, but use joins is a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using containable behavior for such scenarios is indeed hectic and retrieves a lot of unnecessary data. You may have to unbind and unset the unwanted ones.

As an alternative, I'd suggest you to use joins. It's a lot faster and way more flexible, especially for situations like the one you've mentioned.

You could refer to these links:

[CakePHP CookBook: Associations and joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

[CakePHP: Joining multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079908/cakephp-find-method-with-join)

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: I thought it was the opposite, use Containable would be the best practice for these scenarions. Thank you. I'll use joins.